# No injection source found for a parameter in rest-service with jaxrs

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs

I have the problem, that two methods of my rest service bring the error on deploy, that there is no injection source.

My Service looks like this:

```
@Path("/chatservice")
public class ChatServiceImpl implements ChatService{

@POST
@Path("/registerToServer")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Response registerToServer(User user) {

    UserList userListObject = getAllChatableUsers(user);

    return Response.status(200).entity(userListObject).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/sendMessage")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Response sendMessage(Message message) {
    boolean isSuccess = putMessageIntoDatabase(message);

    return Response.status(200).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/getAllMessagesForUser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Response getAllMessagesForUser(UserWithRecipient userWithRecipient) {

    return Response.status(200).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/getAllMessagesForUser/{numberOfMessages}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Response getMessagesForUser(@PathParam("numberOfMessages") int numberOfMessages, UserWithRecipient userWithRecipient) {

    return Response.status(200).build();
}
```

The Class whith the Problem is the following:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(User.class)
@XmlRootElement
public class UserWithRecipient {

private User user;
private User recipient;

public UserWithRecipient() {
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public User getRecipient() {
    return recipient;
}

public void setRecipient(User recipient) {
    this.recipient = recipient;
}
}
```

And the error I get is the following:

```
 [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response de.hszg.fei.ws.service.ChatServiceImpl.getMessagesForUser(int,de.hszg.fei.ws.model.UserWithRecipient) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class de.hszg.fei.ws.service.ChatServiceImpl, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@6da34189]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response de.hszg.fei.ws.service.ChatServiceImpl.getMessagesForUser(int,de.hszg.fei.ws.model.UserWithRecipient), parameters=[Parameter [type=int, source=numberOfMessages, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class de.hszg.fei.ws.model.UserWithRecipient, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']]]
```

Can you tell me what is the problem with this class. I also don't understand, why the `sendMessage()` method doesn't brings the same problem.

Comment: What JSON provider are you using?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found out that the problem was, that I imported the wrong `@PathParam` Annotation.

Comment: Eclipse suggests `javax.websocket.server.PathParam` before `javax.ws.rs.PathParam` ... but the second one has to be chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer to add a bit more context to the question / accepted answer.

As [Daniel Müssig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3064489/daniel-m%C3%BCssig) described in his answer, I too used the wrong @PathParam annotation (I was using the one from javax.websocket.server, but obviously it should be the one from javax.ws.rs).

Here are some more error messages that I ran into, that might hopefully help some googlers out there!

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type [... more specific method data on this line]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:553) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:182) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:348) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:345) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:345) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found, i was using **com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam**. Right import is **org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam**. This fixed my issue.

Reference - https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/multipart-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/multipart/webapp/MultiPartFieldInjectedResource.java